# How to instantiate Codeigniter3 controllers in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, codeigniter-3

So I have gotten codeigniter and phpunit playing nice, but I'm a little confused as to how to instantiate controllers.

I've found a few guides that suggest that you should test controllers like so:

```
class Welcome_test extends TestCase
{
    public function test_index()
    {
        $output = $this->request('GET', ['Welcome', 'index']);
        $this->assertContains('<title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>', $output);
    }
}
```

While that looks good on paper, an error informed me that TestCase has no request() method.

The same guide shows testing a model like this:

```
class Inventory_model_test extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->resetInstance();
        $this->CI->load->model('shop/Inventory_model');
        $this->obj = $this->CI->Inventory_model;
    }

    public function test_get_category_list()
    {
        $expected = [
            1 => 'Book',
            2 => 'CD',
            3 => 'DVD',
        ];
        $list = $this->obj->get_category_list();
        foreach ($list as $category) {
            $this->assertEquals($expected[$category->id], $category->name);
        }
    }

    public function test_get_category_name()
    {
        $actual = $this->obj->get_category_name(1);
        $expected = 'Book';
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

This led me to try something else, and I now have &instance in the test object's public property CI so that I can access it like so:

```
...$this->CI...
```

I assume a method of that object will instantiate the controller by name. Something like:

```
$this->CI->load->controller('ControllerClassName');
```

Does such a method exist? When I use it, do I just access the class like so?

```
$this->CI->load->controller('ControllerClassName');
$c = new $this->CI->ControllerClassName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting again with my phpunit integration. This time I used [kenjis ci-phpunit-test](https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test). The examples from the question now work properly.